# How to choose the meaning of words from many meanings to prepare for tests

Tags: vocabulary, dictionaries

To increase my vocabulary i collect word from my daily study and then find them into Cambridge dictionary. But one word has many meaning. It is sometimes hard to memorize all of them and it is also time consuming. But i don't understand which meaning have to chose.So how i will understand that which meaning is more important and i have to memories.

I was preparing for GRE. I have quit long time on my hand. I have read a book named " Barron's Essential Words for GRE". There words given with their meaning. I have also read another book named "Barron's Essential Words for TOEFL". Both of the two books have listed some words with their meaning.These book have given one or two meaning. But when i have searched those words in dictionary, i have found many meanings rather than the meaning they have listed. Then i got confused.

Comment: @user3169: OP is preparing for the GRE. That's the context, that's what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

> These book have given one or two meaning. But when I have searched those words in dictionary, I have found many meanings rather than the meaning they have listed.

If a word has fewer meanings in the exam book than it has in the dictionary, then I'd assume the meanings listed in the exam book are the ones most likely to be used on the test.

> One word has many meaning. It is sometimes hard to memorize all of them and it is also time consuming. But I don't understand which meaning have to chose. So how I will understand that which meaning is more important and I have to memorize.

Sorry, there is no easy trick to this. However, many dictionaries tend to put the more common meanings first – so that might help.

When you are building vocabulary, I wouldn't worry too much about memorizing ALL the definitions. The first one or two should be fine. In general, I think it would be better to memorize the first two definitions of twelve words than the first eight definitions of three words.

Dictionaries are meant to be reference books, which means you can go back later when you need to learn more about a word. Dictionary entries are not meant to be memorized like flash cards.

Good luck!